# React Native: await AsyncStorage.getItem no response

Tags: react-native, asynchronous

I have two buttons, the first one is to set item for `AsyncStorage` and the second one is to get item for `AsyncStorage`.

```
<Button title = 'click' onPress = {() => {
   let item = '1234'
   AsyncStorage.setItem('data', item )
   alert('saved')
   }
 }
/>
<Button title = 'click2' onPress = { async() => {
   let item = await AsyncStorage.getItem('data')
   alert(item)
   console.log(item)
  }
 }
/>
```

For some reason, after I clicked the first button to save the data, I tried to click the second button, but the `alert` function and the `console.log` did not work.
Can someone help me to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setItem` is also asynchronous, and you’re not waiting for it to resolve. It’s possible (though it does seem unlikely if you’re really using human-facing buttons) that your data isn’t saved in time.

It’s also possible that either or both calls are failing but you’re not handling their errors - both should be called with `await` and wrapped in `try` / `catch`, certainly in a real-world app. Again though I’m doubtful because in dev you’d normally see a warning for an unhandled promise rejection.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. What turned out to be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
_saveData(data) {
    AsyncStorage.setItem("data", data);
};

_getData = async () => {
    try {
        let data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('data');
        console.log(data)

    } catch (e) {
        //console.log("error", e)
    }
};


<Button title = 'set data' onPress = {() => this._saveData("1234")} />
<Button title = 'get data' onPress = {() => this._getData ()} />
```